# search for a string from property file and print the lines in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, file, text

I am trying to print the line of a file if the string is matched from the list.

**Step #1** -
I am getting list of Accounts/users from a db as txt file and the content will be looking like this

list_from_db.txt

```
userA
userB
userC
```

I am converting this .txt file to a list first with the below code -

```
lineList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("list_from_db.txt")]
print(lineList)
```

*output-*

```
['userA','userB','userC']
```

**Step #2** -

Now i am searching this list of strings with a property file and the content will looks like this

*user.properties*

```
GIT_url = https://giturl:9000
url_usercontent= redirection
value.userB.duplicate=yes
checkif.userC.exist=on
```

My code to check if the content from my list is present in this file  -

```
   with open("user.properties") as f:
          file_content = f.read()
    #lineList is a list which i am taking from Step #1
    for x in lineList:
        if x in file_content:
            print(x)
```

*my output-*

```
userB
userC
```

I am able to print the matching string but i need the entire line from my property file.

*Expected output* -

```
value.userB.duplicate=yes
checkif.userC.exist=on
```

**Edit #1(Edge case)-**
If my list contains a string "user" then it should only consider that value instead of relative value.

For eg : if i have my list like this -

```
['user','userA','userB','userC']
```

It should not print me the all output relevant to "user" from the list-

it should still give me the expected output as mentioned above -

```
value.userB.duplicate=yes
checkif.userC.exist=on
```

it should not print the output like this -

```
url_usercontent= redirection
value.userB.duplicate=yes
checkif.userC.exist=on
```

Kindly help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
users=['userA','userB','userC']

with open('user.properties') as f:
    file.content = f.read()

    contents = file_content.split('\n')

    for content in contents:
        for user in users:
            if ('.'+user+'.') in content:
                print(content)
```

Comment: Can we get the exact string match from the file, Because this solution is giving me relative results, for example if my list is having a string "user" , Then it is printing all three entries from my property file.

Comment: If we can use the dots as delimiters for the substring you could do something like: `if ('.'+user+'.') in content:`

Comment: yes, may be dots before and after or simple text in a URL like https://host/user/ID. Your solution is printing me the results if that also covers the edge case which i had mentioned in the EDIT i can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
with open(text, 'r') as f: 
content1 = f.readlines() 
content2 = [x.strip() for x in content1]
pattern = "my_pattern" 
for z in content2:
    if pattern:
        print(z)
```

Comment: it is printing my entire propertyfile

Comment: Its printing me the result in Vertical order.